# Gemination of plosives in final positions following a consonant

Tags: pronunciation, ambiguity, phonetics, doubled-consonants, allophones

Whenever a plosive like p,t,k follows a consonant in the final position, it is always released or else it can't be heard at all. For example: lamp, act, thank, etc. Yet in the word lamppost, the first 'p' is unreleased. Shouldn't this 'p' be released lest the word be perceived as 'lam-post' instead of 'lamp-post'? It is also along this line of reasoning that affricates can't be geminated after all: 'which chair' should be pronounced with two 'tʃ' sounds or else it will be heard as 'which air'. Does this mean that we should only geminate a plosive at the end of a word when it is preceded by a vowel and apply the same rule for affricates when it is preceded by a consonant ?

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong; the /p/ in the word *lamppost* is geminated in English, and this makes *lamp post* distinguishable from *lamb post* — it's even one of the examples in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) on gemination.

Comment: The difference can be subtle to hear, but it's very rarely ambiguous unless you live on a street with both lighting and tethered sheep.

Comment: Is it possible to differentiate between 'lamb' and 'lamp' with an unreleased stop ? I know the context might be enough but I'd appreciate it if you could elucidate me on the technical details. I can't tell 'lamppost' and 'lamb post' when I pronounce them myself. Also the transcription on the wiki indicates the geminated 'p' is an unreleased one followed by an aspirated one.

Comment: @BrackBruno: the difference is not between *lamb* and *lamp* (with an unreleased stop) but between *lamb post* and *lamp post*. In *lamp post* the /p/ is longer — this is what *geminated* means. I don't know if anybody can hear a difference between *lamb* and *lamp* with an unreleased stop; this distinction is certainly irrelevant to English.

Comment: Surely this question depends, at least in part, on where and how you learnt to speak English. A native BrE speaker, particularly one brought up on a diet of RP, would pronounce both `which chair` and `lamppost` with both sounds enunciated.

Comment: Now that you say it, I kind of figure it out now but i think it would take some time to sink in. On an unrelated note, can a plosive be unreleased if it's in a final position preceded by a consonant like the examples I listed above ? Or it has to be released ? I just can't help but notice that because of my native tongue. We never release a plosive in a coda if preceded by a vowel.

Comment: @PeterJennings: listening to British English speakers saying "lamppost" on Youglish, most of them geminate the /p/, a few of them pronounce the /p/ twice (this surprises me; I don't think we do this in American English), and a few of them pronounce it in a way that sounds very much like "lamb post".

Comment: @PeterShor Erm, surely not true. If one can hear the difference between *lamb* and *lamp* (and one can!) then that surely is as good a cue as any for the difference between *lamb post* and *lamp post*! Incidentally, Brack Bruno, not only can we hear the unreleased stop at the end of *lamp*, the voiceless stop causes pre-fortis clipping making the vowel + [m] much shorter in *lamp* than in *lamb*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Can we really hear it ? I've tried some combinations of pre-final consonants plus plosive. Some I can easily tell apart even with an unreleased final like 'help' but others can't seem to be pronounced that way without being distorted into other words or sounding pretty weird like 'bump', 'bent', 'bank' or 'ask'. So can these endings be 'geminated' and at the same time not be confused with other words ? Most of the examples about gemination in textbook just contain a plosive with a vowel preceding it and I can't seem to find any hard and fast rule regardind this.

Comment: @Araucaria: But the reason we can tell *lamp* from *lamb* is phonetically different from the reason we can tell *lamppost* from *lamb post*. The reason we can tell *lamb post* from *lamppost* is gemination, and none of the consonants is geminated in *lamb* or *lamp*.